# "Django deprecated" error in Django-Admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, deprecation-warning

When I am using django-admin startproject api then it is opening file name django-admin.py and the code looks like this :

```
#!C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\api\venv\Scripts\python.exe 

## When the django-admin.py deprecation ends, remove this script.

import warnings
from django.core import management 

try:
    from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango40Warning
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError(
        'django-admin.py was deprecated in Django 3.1 and removed in Django '
        '4.0. Please manually remove this script from your virtual environment '
        'and use django-admin instead.'
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    warnings.warn(
        'django-admin.py is deprecated in favor of django-admin.',
        RemovedInDjango40Warning,
    )
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

I am using virtual environment. I am not getting how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer:

Use **django-admin.exe** instead of **django-admin** because **django-admin.py** is deprecated.

Example:
**django-admin.exe** startproject NEW_PROJECT_NAME
**django-admin.exe** startapp NEW_APP_NAME

---

### Long answer:

If you use the command "**where** django-admin" (Windows) / "**whereis** django-admin" (Linux), you will see that there are probably two shortcuts.

In my case:
C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\django-admin.exe
C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\django-admin.py

I suppose that using an **.exe** extension file is faster than using the **.py** python extension file.

There may be another solution, I haven't tried to delete the file with "py" extension (django-admin.py), I just found that the fastest solution was to use "**django-admin.exe** startproject PROJECT_NAME", and so on.

Comment: I apreciate your highlighting of the executable file, but would like to have changed it to code formatting. Unfortunately, the edit queue is already full, probably somebody else was faster in suggesting this. You can do that by using the tools above or the respective syntax like `inline code` (use this accent: ```, the syntax is shown in the tooltip at mouseover).

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is probably to uninstall and reinstall Django in your virtual environment, if you're okay using the latest version of 3.2:

```sh
pip uninstall Django
pip install 'Django<4'
```